# Update "npm" package and GitHub

Tags: node.js, github, npm

I have published a package with `npm`, I also have it on `github`. Now I fixed a bug in the package and I am lost, how should I proceed with updating? Publish new version  with `npm publish` or `git commit`? Or both? What is the right procedure?

Comment: These are totally independent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to fix the bug in your npm package, increase version number and publish it.

If you want to fix the bug in your git repository, do `git commit && git push`.

In most cases you'll probably want to do both.